# How to properly solve "git-gui: command not found" on Arch Linux?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, path, git

The [Arch Linux `git` package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/git/) installs `git-gui` under `/usr/lib/git-core/`.

This means `git-gui` cannot be launched directly from the terminal without specifying the full path:

> `$ git-gui`
>   bash: git-gui: command not found
>   `$ which git-gui`
>   which: no git-gui in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)

I'm at a doublt as to what would be the way to *properly* solve this.

1. Add `/usr/lib/git-core/` to system-wide `$PATH`?
2. Create symlink to `/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui` under `/usr/local/bin`?
3. Report a bug in the Arch Linux package? Or upstream?
4. Do nothing - this is not a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: `git gui` still works, right? Do you need to run it as a single word for some reason (and if so, what reason?)?

Comment: p.2, but from `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @MichaelHomer It does - and to be honest, I didn't know that was possible at all. I can settle with that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. All git sub-commands are installed to there — you will also find `git-commit` there, though probably as a link to the main binary for efficiency these days — and the main `git` command knows where to find them.

Any executable `git-X` there becomes available as `git X` automatically, and that's the expected way to access them rather than by path or the hyphenated name. `git gui` is the normal way to access the `git-gui` executable, and is also what `man git-gui` will suggest.

Comment: I'll usually wait a little longer before accepting an answer, but this one is right on.